Cannot connect to SocketIO server
This is my main.rs file:
use axum::routing::get;
use log::info;
use serde_json::Value;
use socketioxide::{
    extract::{AckSender, Bin, Data, SocketRef},
    SocketIo,
};
use tracing_subscriber::FmtSubscriber;

fn on_connect(socket: SocketRef, Data(data): Data<Value>) {
    info!("Socket.IO connected: {:?} {:?}", socket.ns(), socket.id);
    socket.emit("auth", data).ok();

    socket.on(
        "message",
        |socket: SocketRef, Data::<Value>(data), Bin(bin)| {
            info!("Received event: {:?} {:?}", data, bin);
            socket.bin(bin).emit("message-back", data).ok();
        },
    );

    socket.on(
        "message-with-ack",
        |Data::<Value>(data), ack: AckSender, Bin(bin)| {
            info!("Received event: {:?} {:?}", data, bin);
            ack.bin(bin).send(data).ok();
        },
    );
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(FmtSubscriber::default())?;

    let (layer, io) = SocketIo::new_layer();

    io.ns("/", on_connect);
    io.ns("/custom", on_connect);

    let app = axum::Router::new()
        .route("/", get(|| async { "Hello, World!" }))
        .layer(layer);

    info!("Starting server");

    let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:3000").await.unwrap();
    axum::serve(listener, app).await.unwrap();

    Ok(())
}

and this is my Cargo.toml:
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.36.0", features = ["full"] }
axum = "0.7.4"
serde = { version = "1.0.196", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.108"
tracing-subscriber = { version = "0.3.18", features = ["fmt"] }
diesel = "2.1.4"
diesel_logger = "0.3.0"
diesel_cli = "2.1.0"
socketioxide = "0.12"
log = "^0"
tracing = "0.1.37"

Problem is that when I run server, only HTTP part works, I get Hello, World! from path /, but when I try to connect to it using some SocketIO client on path / or /custom, I get only "connecting" and doesn't connect, how could I fix it? My goal is to run both HTTP server with some API endpoints and SocketIO server for real time communication.
